# Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max after upgrade Flutter to newer version

Tags: ios, flutter

I've updated to FLutter 2.0.1 and now I am not able to run my app.
This is the error that I have:

```
Xcode build done.                                           34.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/ran/Development/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.m:367:23: warning: 'mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            configuration.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = true;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                          mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback
    In module 'WebKit' imported from /Users/ran/Development/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.h:6:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Headers/WKWebViewConfiguration.h:211:28: note: 'mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property (nonatomic) BOOL mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback", ios(8.0, 9.0));
                               ^
    /Users/ran/Development/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.m:374:23: warning: 'mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            configuration.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                          mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback
    In module 'WebKit' imported from /Users/ran/Development/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.h:6:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Headers/WKWebViewConfiguration.h:211:28: note: 'mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property (nonatomic) BOOL mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback", ios(8.0, 9.0));
                               ^
    2 warnings generated.
    ../../../Development/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.19.1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:52:59: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
            context != null ? Localizations.localeOf(context, nullOk: true) : null,
                                                              ^^^^^^
    ../../../Development/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:413:17: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
      static Locale localeOf(BuildContext context) {
                    ^^^^^^^^

    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

Flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on macOS 11.2.2 20D80 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.2.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.53.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

And this is my flutter run --verbose

```
[ +103 ms] Could not build the application for the simulator.
[   +3 ms] Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
[   +3 ms] "flutter run" took 39,841ms.
[   +4 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:644:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1157:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1009:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:278:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:234:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #12     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #14     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #15     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:73:10)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #16     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
```

I have tried some online solutions like flutter clean and flutter run but it doesn't work.
Can you help me to solve this problem? Thank you and I really appreciate it.

Comment: `Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. `  open ios\Runner.xcworkapce. and check `Signing & Capabilities`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved the problem by replacing mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction with mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback in the files.

Comment: @Ran I have the same problem, but don't have mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback declared anywhere. Is there anything else to check to resolve the issue?

Comment: @AlexKost I think it is located in folder Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView. Or you can try to downgrade your flutter version. It would work

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by `webview_flutter` plugin using a deprecated function on iOS 9. More details are discussed on this [issue ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76370). This issue should be fixed in the latest version of the plugin.